# How to invoking code sequentially using Promises

Tags: promise

I am just starting to learn how to use Promises as I have been experimenting with callbacks so far.
I am trying the code below:
It should invoke promise func1, wait 1 second, check func1's returned value, then invoke promise func2, wait 1 second and then check func2's returned value.

When I run it, I actually get this output:

```
In func1
func1 sent: 1
func2 sent: undefined
```

so it is clear the func2 is not being invoked.

Could someone assist a Promis newbie in his first code experiments?
Thank you

```
class A {

    func1(param) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Use param...
            console.log("In func1");
            setTimeout(() => resolve("1"), 1000);
        });
    }

    func2(param) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Use param...
            console.log("In func2");
            setTimeout(() => resolve("2"), 1000);
        });
    }
}

const a = new A();
a.func1("arg1")
.then((value) => {
    // Check the value of value returned from func1
    console.log("func1 sent: " + value);
}).then((value) => {
    // Check the value of value returned from func2
    console.log("func2 sent: " + value);
});
```

I based my code on this. Here there is no explicit call to the 2nd function and it works... Why doesn't it work in solution?

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("In func1");
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);

}).then(function(value) {
    console.log("func1 sent: " + value);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("In func2");
        setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 1000);
    });

}).then(function(value) { 
    console.log("func2 sent: " + value);

});
```

Comment: Well your code literally doesn't invoke `a.func2()` anywhere. It seems you simply missed a line.

Comment: Btw, I would suggest not to use a `class` here if it doesn't have any state and you don't need multiple instances. Just write `const a = { func1(param) { … }, func2(param) { … } };`.

Comment: I need the class as in my "real" code I do have a state. 
See above what I based my question on.

Comment: Try comparing the working and the non-working snippet line by line. What's missing in the first `then` chain?